# In .xml file design is not showing in whole project

Tags: java, android

design page is not showing

1. I have tried with invalidating catches/restart.
2. Clean and rebuild.
3. Tried with Theme
   `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`
4. Update the studio too

No error is showing in the entire project and it's running successfully.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the XML file?

Comment: it is not for a single XML file. getting error in the whole project more than 40+ xml file are there.

Answer (score 1):

Close the Android Studio.

Go to the .AndroidStudio3.2 --> system --> caches. Now,delete the whole caches folder and start the Android Studio and i have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to specify a width and height for some views of your layout. I believe these parameters are required.

Comment: how can i find out the error as project is running smoothly. there are 40+ .xml file. even not getting any error hints from any .xml.

Comment: I think it's in the layout where you display the preview that you have the problem (on one or more) view

Comment: It's quite surprising that you can compile. Because if I remove the width and height attributes from my views it is impossible for me to compile.

Comment: I always use height width as match or wrap. Still i don't know why did i get that kind of problem. After clearing the catch from .AndroidStudio3.2. Problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your layout is missing the "layout_width" or "layout_height" parameter. Those are required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think is an issue is about "layout_width" or "layout_height" parameter. Those are the required parameters. if isn't then please change a theme and android version from a preview screen.